# How to analyze thread dumps in Java to minimize high CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage, thread-dump, disruptor-pattern

I'm trying to read text file and insert into database with `Disruptor`.

But I find that the CPU usage is too high (200%, according to `top` command).

I'm new to performance tuning and thread dump analysis. I don't know what's going wrong.

So I execute `top -H` and find the two highest threads (both are 99%), and find the thread dump:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f54a4006800 nid=0x79ab runnable [0x00007f54a8340000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.SingleProducerSequencer.next(SingleProducerSequencer.java:104)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.SingleProducerSequencer.next(SingleProducerSequencer.java:79)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(RingBuffer.java:207)
    at com.xxx.xxx.connectivity.quickfixj.FixMessageReceiver.onMessage(FixMessageReceiver.java:105)
    at com.xxx.xxx.database.DatabaseService.start(DatabaseService.java:110)
    at com.xxx.xxx.database.DatabaseService.main(DatabaseService.java:168)


"pool-2-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f54a426d800 nid=0x79bc runnable [0x00007f5492a37000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.SingleProducerSequencer.next(SingleProducerSequencer.java:104)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.SingleProducerSequencer.next(SingleProducerSequencer.java:79)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(RingBuffer.java:207)
    at com.cimb.reporting.connectivity.jms.DatabaseEventHandler.publish2DbRingBuffer(DatabaseEventHandler.java:49)
    at com.xxx.xxx.connectivity.jms.DatabaseEventHandler.onEvent(DatabaseEventHandler.java:39)
    at com.xxx.xxx.connectivity.jms.DatabaseEventHandler.onEvent(DatabaseEventHandler.java:15)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Basically these two threads are going to publish data to Disruptor. I create `Disruptor` in this way:**

```
Disruptor<TradeEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<TradeEvent>(TradeEvent.TRADE_EVENT_FACTORY,
                properties.dbRingbufferSize(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                ProducerType.SINGLE, new BlockingWaitStrategy());
```

Please help me and analyze the thread dump to find the root cause of high CPU usage.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful a single thread dump will be... Perhaps a profiler would work better?

Comment: Which profiler do you suggest?

Comment: I'm only familiar with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), but it seems to do everything I need it to do. There should be a built-in version for your JDK as the command-line tool `jvisualvm` if you don't want to download a separate application. The two are really more or less the same thing though.

Comment: jvisualvm could run in linux command line environment?

Comment: It should be bundled with the JDK from Java 6 (I think?) and up. Fire up your command line and give it a try (unless you're talking about a no-GUI command line environment, in which case I don't think it'll work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faced exactly the same problem: 100% cpu usage on my machine Intel Core i3-3220 with 16GB memory with one broker (Xmx 2G), one client (Xmx2G) and without any message in a ringbuffer.

Quick profiling shows that Thread.yield() consumes about 70-80% of cpu.

It is turned out the YieldingWaitStrategy is not a proper strategy in my case.
So in my case quick fix was to set the wait strategy into BlockingWaitStrategy:

```
Disruptor<MessageEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<MessageEvent>(eventFactory, RING_BUFFER_SIZE, executor, ProducerType.SINGLE, new BlockingWaitStrategy());
```

---

**UPDATE**

JProfiler for YieldingWaitStrategy 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I had figured it out the `SleepWaitStrategy` was the root cause. When I change to `BlockingWaitStrategy`, everything is fine. BTW, how to you know Thread.yield() consumes about 70-80% of cpu by profiling?

Comment: I used JProfiler in Sample mode and found stacktrace for the method which consumes most cpu. See attached picture

Answer (score 1):

High CPU utilization is ok if there is actually some work in progress. i.e. if there are many live threads performing, the net CPU usage for java application will always be at its peak. It is usually instantaneous, i.e. should get normal again when there are no tasks.

I would suggest to:

> 1. Take multiple thread dumps (3-4) after a fix interval (1-2 seconds) 
>       (can use kill command on
>      linux, jstack , jvisualvm, jconsole on all systems with jdk)
> 2. execute `ps -mo pid,lwp,stime,time,%cpu,%mem -C java | less` . This will list the lightweight processes under the java application's process id.
> 3. Get the process ids of the processes `LWP` with highest cpu/memory % (as targeted)
> 4. convert the lwp ids in to hexadecimal values, can use `echo "obase=16; 255" | bc`
> 5. Map these hex ids as `nid='some_hex_vlaue'` in the thread dump to find the details of thread corresponding to high cpu usage.
>      **e.g**: "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f54a4006800 `nid=0x79ab` runnable [0x00007f54a8340000]
>
> Now we know the thread/s within the java process with highest
>   resource(can be used for both memory/cpu%) usage.

I would also recommend to attach your jvm process to `jvisualvm` or `jconsole` and reproduce the problem, this way you can monitor your application’s state at all the time (from normal to issue reproduction) and take snapshots for reference.
Both are good enough to perform any java threads or memory related profiling.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/   
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Analyzing thread dumps can only point to the problem areas. At times its tricky, usually with high impact, but the cause and fix will be small. 
Actual cause would usually  be either the way application is coded. i.e. How concurrency is managed. If a process is listening infinitely instead of waiting for notification, deadlocks due to synchronization issues etc or the system environment/external interfaces. i.e. file r/w on disk or remote locations, transfer using a ftp APIs or  may be db operations etc.

Here is one useful post at dzone: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't follow your steps when you say "look for waiting or blocked threads". When the cpu is high, shouldn't we be worried about RUNNABLE threads since those would be the ones consuming the cpu? Do threads in waiting, timed_waiting or blocked threads burn CPU cycles?

Comment: yes the steps were messed up, inaccurate and not well targeted as per question. Have edited them  to suit context.

Comment: I have recently used java mission control - flight recording feature. It can help you to almost point to the code piece that's causing the issue. Analyzing thread dumps might not be needed.

Comment: You are right. But then what if you want  this info at some client location/remote systems where such tools are not available(or the jvm process cant be connected remotely). a simple `kill -3` to obtain thread dump and `ps` can serve

Comment: True. Though jmc could be used for remote recording, at times we can't get anything other than thread dumps

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit old however consider that in most recent JDK (f.e. Java 11) the CPU usage is exposed in the Thread Dump. Example:

```
jstack -l 5213 | grep cpu
"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=4.88ms elapsed=7027.22s tid=0x0000dedewfewwewe nid=0x3456 waiting on condition  [0x00007f386cc0c000]
```

References: [Find which Java Thread is hogging your CPU](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/monitoring/finding-which-java-threads-are-consuming-your-cpu/)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at a java profiler. For example VisualVM, which will analyze your CPU and RAM use in real time.